# AWS Opsworks undeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks, undeploy

I am in the middle of settings up a nice deployment infrastructure for the company I am working for. We developed on single App, we have to deploy multiple times having different URLs assigned to each App.

Deploying works quite well, no problems here.

Removing, or undeploying is the problem I am facing right now.
If I delete one App, using the AWS Opsworks console, Opsworks is executing my undeploy script. The Problem is, I am not getting any information about the App I just deleted, I just get information about the remaining Apps.

The background is I have to delete the nginx user, the database and its user and the folder structure of the App itself.
I tried every data_bags given by aws: aws_opsworks_* :

```
search("aws_opsworks_app").each do |app|
  Chef::Log.info("undeploy: #{app}")
end
```

thanks in advance

Link.de

Comment: Could you show us the contents of `node[:deploy]` before and after the undeploy lifecycle event?

Comment: I assigned my undeploy script to the undeploy lifecycle event in the opsworks configuration. If I log the content of node[:deploy] the result is nil. I don't really know how I can read the value of node[:deploy] before and after the event.

Comment: Removing Chef tag as this is not Chef related (i.e. only Opsworks stuff).